# jquery hide and show button

Tags: jquery, html

I have select and input button control inside loop. Initially input button is hidden with css property display:none; I want to show input button when select value gets change with the help of jquery. Only respective input should be visible not all. Please help me out

```
<td>                              
    <select id="isactive" class="select_<?php echo($i++);?>">
        <option  value="single" <?php if($currentStatus == "S") echo("selected=\"true\""); ?> >Single</option>
        <option value="double" <?php if($currentStatus == "D") echo("selected=\"true\""); ?>>Double</option>
        <option value="no" <?php if($currentStatus == "N") echo("selected=\"true\""); ?>>No</option>                          
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="updatebtn" id="updateoptinbtn_<?php echo($j++);?>" value="Update" />                                  
</td>
```

JQuery

```
$(".select").change(function(){
    $("#updateoptinbtn").show();
});
```

Comment: please post your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ for understanding to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.closest()` and `.find()`

```
$('select').on('change' , function(){
     $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="button"]').show();
                           //OR
    $(this).closest('td').find('.updatebtn').show();
 });
```

Comment: finally worked with $('select').change(function(){

     $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="button"]').show();
 });

Answer (score 0):

Your classes and ids are dynamically created using php `updateoptinbtn_<?php echo($j++);?>"` so css selectors you used are not the correct ones. Please use the code below:

```
 $('select').change(function(){
     $(this).next('input[type="button"]').show();
 })
```

Comment: thanks, your function is getting called but input is still hidden. Does it need any change in css ?